# Dialog which shows an error is not visible when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: bug, popup

Today, I reviewed "suggested edits" and I Approve/Reject edit. When going for the next review one, error message box is displayed without any error message as below.

[image]

When I show its HTML it looks like:

```
<div class="message message-error message-dismissable" style="display: block; position: absolute;">
  <div class="message-inner">
  <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
  <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no any message then why it shows? 
I think there is some bug right?

Comment: Happens to me most of the time ( sometimes, when I click using my mouse, it happens to be two clicks in quick succession because my mouse has a problem ). I think that it can be reproduced by pressing any ( or maybe some ) button in quick succession.

Comment: Yes same bug also happens when i double click on close below any post.

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. The dialog is visible if I press "close" more than one time within 3 seconds.

Comment: Ohh ok. That dialog hide behind *"why should this question be closed?"* dialog.

Comment: @CoolGuy: _because my mouse has a problem_ Ah, the old "I didn't really mean to double click" excuse. ;)